# Kinesis Triggered Lambda Parse Aggregated Records

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to write a node js lambda that will get automagically  triggered via kinesis stream.  The producer side leverages aggregation where each record sent to kinesis contains 1 or more user records.  Unfortunately i am unable to change that code.  My lambda is configured to have a batch size of 1 and the below code will decode as follows to a string.

`var result = Buffer.from(event.Records[0].kinesis.data,'base64').toString('ascii');`

This gives me a leading section of

`s\t\u001aB\n$5189d540-80f1-11e6-98e4-ca81484488df\n$3fd42f70-7468-11e6-b1c7-ca81484488df\n$19665d50-4d20-11e6-a9aa-ca81484488df\n$dd7e25a0-4dda-11e6-a9aa-ca81484488df\u001a\u0005\u0006\b\u0000\u001a\u0000\u0006`

then between the actual user records i get something like this

`\u001a\t\u0006\b\u0001\u001a\u0004\u0006`

then at the end i get a trailing section like this

`7~r8\u001ag,\u001ae\u001c#r\u0014Z`

My question here is does anyone know of a node js aws-sdk function or 3rd party npm module that would convert this either base64 input string or my decoded string into an array of actual messages from kinesis?

Comment: Looks like this might be promising https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-kinesis-agg

Comment: Maybe you can find an example to library above; https://github.com/awslabs/lambda-streams-to-firehose/blob/master/index.js